# How to hide keyboard on page load in Tablet?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am working on a Asp.net project. In that I have a specific webpage, in which on page load one of the first text box get focus. So we can start typing.

Its working well in desktop computers. I tested this on a tablet, where everything works perfect, but on focus of the textbox virtual keyboard gets popup.

This is happening on page load, so half of the interface gets blocked by the keyboard. I want to stop the keyboard from poping up on the first focus in that device.

I can stop the focus, but my client wants the focus property in computer screen, but not necessory in tablet mode.

How do I hide the keyboard on the pageload focus?

This is the code to focus the textbox

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#txtItemSearch').focus();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check window.orientation is defined aren't based on that you can have focus code.

```
if (typeof window.orientation == 'undefined') { 
    //Your Desktop Code
}
```